# U v. Non-U English (2022) - "graveyard" v. "cemetery"

Tags: british-english, class-based-usage

In her essay 'The English Aristocracy', Nancy Mitford classified "graveyard" as U and "cemetery" as Non-U. Is this still the case today (in British English), or have both words become class neutral?

Comment: What is U and non-U?

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin upper class and non-upper class.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin They are terms made famous by the authoress Nancy Mitford, who referenced an academic paper “U and Non-U: An Essay in Sociological Linguistics,” published in a Finnish journal by Alan S. C. Ross

Answer (score 1):

Cemetery and Graveyard are poor examples of U and Non-U and any reference to them should be ignored, as a distinction may be made by any class of person.

**[Cemetery](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cemetery)** (ˈsɛmɪtrɪ) n, pl -teries: a place where the dead are buried, **especially one not attached to a church**

Cemeteries are any land set aside for the burial of the dead and do not have a church, although they usually have a building of some sort to accommodate mourners.

For example: Arlington Cemetery  - Highgate Cemetery

**[Graveyard](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/graveyard)** (ˈɡreɪvˌjɑːd) n (Ecclesiastical Terms) a place for graves; a burial ground, **especially a small one or one in a churchyard.**

This is somewhat loose, but the area containing graves around a church is never called a cemetery: It is the graveyard of the church.

It is possible to have a graveyard not attached to a church, but this is relatively rare.

When discussing U and Non-U, this, from [Nancy Mitford's biographical article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Mitford) on Wikipedia should be read

> During the 1950s Mitford developed the concept of "U" (upper) and "non-U" language, whereby social origins and standing were identified by words used in everyday speech. **She had intended this as a joke**, but many took it seriously, and Mitford was considered an authority on manners and breeding.

Comment: Not entirely a joke. Mitford referenced an academic paper “U and Non-U: An Essay in Sociological Linguistics,” published in a Finnish journal by Alan S. C. Ross, A Birmingham University professor.